# Is it possible to remove the rest on the line from the string in Perl?

Tags: string, perl

For example,

```
##LATER##run ${XXXXXX}/PPPPPPP /name $DDDDD, out $DDDDD, pri 30/
```

I wanna index `##LATER##`, leave `${XXXXXX}/PPPPPPP` only, and remove everything from `/name` to end of line.

Is it possible to do it on perl?

Comment: What do you mean you want to "index `##LATER##`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $yourstring|perl -pe 's/ \/name.*//'
```

[test](http://ideone.com/EwlKkp)

Comment: You might also want to grab the white space before \name... Also, is the "g" needed if this is a one-line string? 's/\s*\name.*//' should also work.

Comment: @keibee , please accept the answer if this solution was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
my $str = '##LATER##run ${XXXXXX}/PPPPPPP /name $DDDDD, out $DDDDD, pri 30/';
my ($f1, $f2, undef) = split / /, $str, 3;
```

suppose there is no blank character in `XXXXXX`.